# Is there anything in the Coffee proposal that doesn't fall inside the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just looking at the [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4501/coffee)'s on-topic question list:

- How do I roast my own coffee beans?
- Does the temperature of the water
  used to make the coffee affect the
  flavour of it?
- When I use my french
  press, I'm getting a lot of grinds in
  my coffee, what can I do to reduce
  this?
- How long does coffee stay
  fresh, and are there ways to increase
  this time, such as freezing?
- What is
  the difference (if any) between a
  blade grinder and a burr grinder and
  when should I use one over the other?

Is merging this proposal into the Seasoned Advice site something that should be explored?  We're already getting a large number of coffee-related questions here (36 tagged coffee, and ~250 returned by searching for "coffee").

Comment: Note that the 250 number includes a huge number of repeated results; the actual number is probably closer to 50 or 60.  I just submitted a [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77575/141911).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does appear that (almost) all of their "on-topic" examples would be perfectly fine here.

I believe that the coffee proposal was created back when there was still some uncertainty as to what kinds of "beverage" questions were on topic here (for the record, I was always in favour of coffee questions).

I suggest you start a discussion *on* Area 51 to give this more visibility.  They just added this feature last week:

[image: Discussion Feature]

I can do it for you but, you deserve the credit for bringing it up.

Comment: I figured I'd get some input from this community before suggesting it there.

Comment: No problem, @Eclipse. I think the issue was settled some time ago here and as you've noted, the precedent is there; we never close any of those questions. There may not be much awareness that those questions are in scope here. On the other hand I wouldn't want to see a *flood* of coffee-related activity that displaces everything else, since it is a pretty niche culinary topic; hopefully that wouldn't happen with only 80 committed.

Comment: I started the discussion there.  We'll see where it goes..

Comment: Discussion link: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/388/should-the-coffee-proposal-be-merged-into-the-existing-seasoned-advice-site